# Converting hex to decimal

Tags: c#

I have an array of strings that are in hex format, for example `{"3d", "20", "5a"}`.

What would be a good way of converting each element of this string to decimal format?

I've tried using `GetBytes()`, but that doesn't seem to work since it sees "3d" as two different characters because it doesn't know that it is in hex format.

`GetBytes()` works fine in a situation like below but not if characters are in hex.

What am I missing here?

```
string a = "T";
byte[] b = {10};
b = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes(a);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [int.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/c09yxbyt.aspx) with NumberStyles.HexNumber.

Answer (score 1):

```
int decValue = int.Parse(hexValue,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Try that.
HexValue is the number in hex format and decValue is in decimal...